# List comprehension in Go

Tags: go

I have an array of structs.

```
var a = [] struct {
    f1 string
    f2 string
}{
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"biz", "baz"},
}
```

I want to pass an array of the `f2` fields to a function, like so

```
var f2s []string
for _, s := range a {
    f2s = append.f2s(s.f2)
}
// f2s = {"bar", "baz"}
SomeFunc(f2s)
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this? In Python I would do `SomeFunc([s.f2 for s in a])`. In a functional language I would do `(SomeFunc (map (lambda (s) (s.f2)) a))`.

Comment: (Ignoring the botched up syntax in your example): No. That's pretty much how you do it. There's neither list comprehension nor map in Go, and loops are very idiomatic.

Comment: That is a slice of structs not an array.  In go arrays and slices are quite different! [Here is the definitive source.](http://golang.org/doc/articles/slices_usage_and_internals.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Go has no list coercion or that like. Your code looks fine. For longer slices it might be better to allocate the proper length with make.

Comment: Ah that's a shame, not sure the clarity is worth the verbosity in this case but I suppose the Go designers would know better than me :)

Comment: For how much longer slices?

Comment: @Willem This depends. Measure. Under appropriate load and conditions.

Answer (score 7):

No, sincerely, they wouldn't.

Maps and lists comprehension is mainstream enough to be considered basic in any modern language.

It's a nice language with great ideas, but I'm still way far from being comfortable, and often times I feel my code is dirty even when it is idiomatic, well structured code in the Go way of doing things.

Hope this changes in the future.